# Will reed switches break in various weather conditions

Tags: temperature, damage, waterproof, humidity, pressure

I will be using an OKI ORD-9216 14mm reed switch in my mailbox, which is outside of my house.
Below is a picture of a reed switch.
[image]

1. I am worried to whether the reed switch's glass will crack due to changes in temperature, humidity, and air pressure?
2. Since the reed switch will be inside the mailbox, does it matter if I have an enclosure for it?
3. Have you guys seen any device that contains a reed switch that is used in harsh weather conditions?

Comment: Do you have a data sheet for the switches you plan on using?

Comment: Almost all of them work up to about \$+125^\circ\$C. (Some are limited to about boiling water.) Almost all of them work down to about \$-40^\circ\$C, though some will work down to perhaps \$-75^\circ\$C and some perhaps only down to \$-20^\circ\$C. They have quite a range, in general.

Comment: Datasheet http://datasheet.octopart.com/ORD-9216-1520-OKI-datasheet-8356857.pdf

Comment: Be careful forming or cropping the leads on a reed switch. Make sure that you carefully clamp between the capsule and the forming or cropping point, or you can easily shock the switch and alter its behaviour or even ruin it.

Comment: During manufacture, the glass didn't crack when the temperature changed from molten glass to room temperature.  It's stable.

Comment: +Whit3rd, Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reed switch itself will not be damaged by extreme weather conditions, however if you do not seal the connections against moisture and contamination your circuit may not work.

Search for 'waterproof reed switch' for commercial products.

Comment: Can I add heat shrink tubing at the open joints to prevent moisture instead?  Apparently, waterproof reed switches are expensive with US shipping from eBay.  https://tinyurl.com/y94uqtfe

Comment: You could try the kind of heat shrink with adhesive inside and try to seal wire insulation to glass. You could also try products from China.

Comment: Also, should I find a casing for all the wires or will the mailman be suspicious?  But wouldn't the mailman accidentally deliver the casing, with the reed switch inside, too!

Comment: I would make it neat- see how garden lights and irrigation valves are wired in your area for ideas. You should wait some time (maybe 12-24hrs) before accepting an answer- otherwise you may discourage a better answer. You can un-accept.

Comment: @NathanRamanathan Search again. There are a lot of Epoxy sealed switches in US$1 shipped range (like [these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/10pcs-Reed-switch-GPS-14A-Vibration-resistant-and-anti-corruption-N-O-MKA-/181846949695?hash=item2a56ec3f3f:g:Q2kAAOSwPe1T3uh2), or [these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-PCS-Normally-Open-Proximity-Magnetic-Sensor-Reed-Switch-Aleph-PS-3150-NEW-/182387778553?hash=item2a7728a3f9:g:CCcAAOSw6DtYT8iK)).